# Issue in keeping buttons stacked on right with position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thank you for checking the issue; the issue I am facing is I have been able to create 3 stacked buttons on right with position absolute and with the help of JQuery I am adding and removing class "open" as well but the issue is when clicked on 1 button it shifts other two buttons also on right. What I would like is, those buttons should remain on right only and the clicked button should move 375px left and when clicked come down to 120px and other two remain on their closed positions only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thank you once again for stopping by and looking into this.

Please refer my present working code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#absolute-right .collapsible_section').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');

  });

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
}

#absolute-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
}

.collapsible_section {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}

.open {
  width: 320px;
}

.collapsible_section a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hidden_content {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

#absolute-right .collapsible_section .hidden_content {
  display: none;
}

#absolute-right .open .hidden_content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="absolute-right">

  <div class="collapsible_section">
    <a href="#">Button A</a>
    <div class="hidden_content">
      <h3>Hidden Heading</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapsible_section">
    <a href="#">Button B</a>
    <div class="hidden_content">
      <h3>Yo Heading</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="collapsible_section">
    <a href="#">Button C</a>
    <div class="hidden_content">
      <h3>hmm Heading</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?? Run the below snippet.
What i did is added `display:flex` property on the parent container and used both `flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` on it. so this is the final changes i made -->

```
#absolute-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#absolute-right .collapsible_section').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');

    });

});
```

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000;
}

#absolute-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}

.collapsible_section {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
}

.open { width: 320px; }

.collapsible_section a {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.hidden_content {
    background: yellow;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
#absolute-right .collapsible_section .hidden_content{ display: none; }
#absolute-right .open .hidden_content{ display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="absolute-right">

        <div class="collapsible_section">
            <a href="#">Button A</a>
            <div class="hidden_content">
                <h3>Hidden Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapsible_section">
            <a href="#">Button B</a>
            <div class="hidden_content">
                <h3>Yo Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapsible_section">
            <a href="#">Button C</a>
            <div class="hidden_content">
                <h3>hmm Heading</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Worked great - thank you very much George, you've saved my day!  take care :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
.collapsible_section {
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   position: relative;
   width: 120px;
   float: right;
   clear: both;}
```

Comment: I flagged this question for not being a real answer. It's lacking fundamental information and explanations.